# postgresql select distinct on column but only if another column doesn't contain a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

so lets say I have this

```
id some_id field_name
0  200     john
1  200     dude
3  200     man
4  201     kevin
5  201     dude
6  201     man
7  203     lisa
8  203     dudet
9  203     not man
```

I want unique some_id's where one of the field items is not equal to kevin (or any other possible field I deem not wanted). The output Im looking for is:

```
200
203
```

I have been able to get ALL of the unique some_id's easily its when I want to filter out the some_id's based on a specific field_name value existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT some_id
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table t2 
                  WHERE field_name = 'kevin' AND t.some_id = t2.some_id);
```

Or `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT some_id
FROM table 
EXCEPT
SELECT some_id
FROM table
WHERE field_name = 'kevin';
```

Comment: Awesome sauce this is exactly what I needed thanks so much. This also makes sense I expected something way more complicated haha.